# Parsing Redirect Response Codes From Redirect URL - PHP

Tags: php, laravel, oauth, http-redirect

Thank you for your time.

My purpose for posting this question was to see **how** I can approach the problem of parsing the authorization code I get from the redirect to use that code in a subsequent function to get the oauth bearer token.

What libraries can I use similar to python's request module and web module to achieve the same goal as the following code?

```
class ILToken(object):

    def GET(self):
        form = web.input(code=None, scope=None)
```

As an outcome, here is the following example. I have a redirect url set to "http://redirect_example.com/oauth/". When I click a button, the instant login link ("https://api.provider.com/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&redirect_uri=http://redirect_example.com/oauth/...") redirects me to "http://redirect_example.com/oauth/?code=ExampleAuthCode".

I've tried making use of the curl library in php with no positive progress using code similar to the following.

**Code**

```
        # Initialize curl request parameters
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, env('INSTANT_LOGIN_URI'));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE); // We'll parse redirect url from header.
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, FALSE);

        # Set variables and execute
        $output = curl_exec($ch);
        $response_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);
        $redirect = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_REDIRECT_URL);
        curl_close($ch);

        # Print Results
        print $redirect;
```

Related articles say to set FOLLOWLOCATION to true and use the CURLINFO_EFFEFCTIVE_URL variable to return the code. This did not work for me. I am using php v7.4 on an ubuntu machine. The php app is using the laravel framework and loading behind an nginx v1.21 web server.

[How can I get the destination URL using cURL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1439040/how-can-i-get-the-destination-url-using-curl)

[PHP CURL redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40148636/php-curl-redirect)

Comment: _"goes to the api provider and redirects me to"_ - I doubt that that it really does that - in this particular scenario. Because those login URLs are supposed to be used in the _front end_ - you send the user there, and the provider decides to grant access, based on that the user is logged in to the _provider's_ site in their browser (or they will be asked to login there first.) If you try and make that same request using cURL - then there will not be any "logged-in" user on their end.

Comment: OAuth is _supposed_ to require this user interaction, you are not supposed to try and "log in" using server-side coding only.

Comment: @CBroe I am looking for a step forward. What do you recommend I do to get and store the authorization code I need to receive the bearer token? 

The equivalent in python is the form = web.input(code=None,scope=None)

Comment: You need to send the user in their browser to the `https://api.provider.com/oauth/authorize` URL, and then you need to exchange the `code` parameter your get in your redirect _uri when they get redirected back to your app, for an access token.