# Redirecting to payumoney in laravel using Curl

Tags: php, laravel, curl, payment-gateway, payumoney

I want to redirect to payumoney gateway from my php server using curl.

I am using laravel framework and i dont want to use html/blade method to trigger payment gateway.

```
$posted = array();

$posted['key'] = $MERCHANT_KEY;
$posted['hash'] = $hash;
$posted['txnid'] = $txnid;
$posted['firstname'] = $firstname;
$posted['email'] = $email;
$posted['phone'] = $phone;
$posted['amount'] = $amount;
$posted['productinfo'] = $productinfo;
$posted['surl'] = $surl;
$posted['furl'] = $furl;
                
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$c = curl_init();

$url = "https://test.payu.in/_payment";
curl_setopt_array($c, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => $url,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 0,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => 1,
    CURLOPT_POST => true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $posted,
));
$response = curl_exec($c);
```

But this code is showing below output and thus doesn't redirect to gateway fully
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/WmDFS.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP CURL redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40148799)

Comment: CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER should set to  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 0,
 instead of     CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,

Comment: @HasanRaza , CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER is already 0

Comment: @linktoahref that post is unclear to me

Comment: for demo you can check the code I have mentioned

Comment: You seem to be confused here; curl functions are for the *server* to make an HTTP request. They have nothing to do with the end user accessing that server. You also aren't explaining what the problem with your code is, or what your expected behaviour is.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<?php

$url = "https://test.payu.in/_payment";
$postdata = http_build_query($posted);
$c = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($c, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => $url,
    CURLOPT_POST => true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $postdata,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => false,
    CURLOPT_HEADER => true,
));
$response = curl_exec($c);

// Close cURL session
curl_close($c);
$redirect_url = '';
$headers = explode("\r\n", $response);
foreach ($headers as $header) {
    if (strpos($header, 'Location: ') === 0) {
        $redirect_url = trim(substr($header, strlen('Location: ')));
        break;
    }
}
if (!empty($redirect_url)) {
    header("Location: $redirect_url");
    exit;
} else {
    echo "Failed to get redirect URL";
}
```

Comment: What was wrong with the original code? What did you change? Explain this answer please.

Comment: CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  is 0 which needs to be 1 where as 0 mean the curl_exec() funct will not return the rsponse of curl request

Comment: curl_exec($c) execute curl request using the function to trigger redirection to pay gateway

Comment: @HasanRaza payment page is loaded fine but after payment success and failure url are not working with your solution

Comment: [edit] your answer to provide a clear explanation of how it answers the question. @anoopKumarSharma if this doesn’t solve the problem why did you mark it accepted?

Answer (score 0):

As per this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40148799), you would have to analyse the response you get from the CURL request.

```
$response = curl_exec($c);
var_dump($response); // Check the contents of response
```

In order to do that, please set the

```
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
```

> true to return the transfer as a string of the return value of curl_exec() instead of outputting it directly.

[`CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php)

Based on the response, you may [redirect](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/responses#redirects) the user to PayUMoney gateway.

```
if ($response === false) {
    // Transaction not created, navigate the user to the error page.
    return redirect('payment-error');
}

// Transaction is created, everything is okay.
return redirect('payment-page');
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$posted = array(
        'key' => $MERCHANT_KEY,
        'hash' => $hash,
        'txnid' => $txnid,
        'firstname' => $firstname,
        'email' => $email,
        'phone' => $phone,
        'amount' => $amount,
        'productinfo' => $productinfo,
        'surl' => $surl,
        'furl' => $furl,
    );



$url = "https://test.payu.in/_payment";
$c = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($c, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => $url,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => false,
    CURLOPT_POST => true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query($posted),
    CURLOPT_HEADER => false,
));
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);

$response = curl_exec($c);
curl_close($c);
```

Redirect to the PayUmoney gateway

```
return Redirect::away($url)->withInput($request->input());
```

Or you may use:

```
header("Location: $url");
exit;
```

Comment: how is redirect going to make use of Curl??